# Experiencing Error "surfplot_canonical_foldunfold() got multiple values for argument 'cdata'" in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to plot a figure, however, the error mentioned above is persisting and I'm lost on any way to fix it.

(I am aware that there are similar posts to mine, however, solutions from those posts have not solved my problem).

**Code:**

```py
def plot_surf(data, window=None, excludeDG=True, density='0p5mm'):
    if window == None:
        im = plt.imshow(data.reshape(-1,1).T);

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,8), subplot_kw={'projection': "3d"})
        fig.set_dpi(300)

        plotting.surfplot_canonical_foldunfold(ax,cdata=data,excludeDG=excludeDG,den=density)

        cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.35, 0.05, 0.3])
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax);
        
    else:
        im = plt.imshow(data.reshape(-1,1).T,vmin=window[0],vmax=window[1]);

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,8), subplot_kw={'projection': "3d"})
        fig.set_dpi(300)

        plotting.surfplot_canonical_foldunfold(ax,cdata=data,excludeDG=excludeDG,den=density, cwindow=window)

        cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.35, 0.05, 0.3])
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax);
```

**Error Message:**

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[198], line 1
----> 1 plot_surf(np.hstack([slm_metacalcleft.t,slm_metacalcright.t]).T)

Cell In[197], line 8, in plot_surf(data, window, excludeDG, density)
      5 fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,8), subplot_kw={'projection': "3d"})
      6 fig.set_dpi(300)
----> 8 plotting.surfplot_canonical_foldunfold(ax,cdata=data,excludeDG=excludeDG,den=density)
     10 cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.35, 0.05, 0.3])
     11 fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax);

TypeError: surfplot_canonical_foldunfold() got multiple values for argument 'cdata'
```

I have tried nearly all solutions posted on this website with no luck (e.g. positional arguments, declaring 'self' etc.).

Comment: What is `plotting`? Is that a package you're using? I don't recognize the `surfplot_canonical_foldunfold` function from matplotlib.

Comment: @jared plotting is a package I'm using in 'hippunfold_toolbox'. I'm not too sure where 'surfplot_canonical_unfold' is from but I know it has to be apart of the hippunfold tool. I should remove the matplotlib tag as I only added it because another error message named matplotlib, but it probably has no relevance. Please let me know what other information I can give you.

Comment: You should add the imports to your question. In general, you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Taking a quick look at some documentation...are you sure it takes `ax` as the first argument, and not `cdata`? Try removing `ax`. `cdata` format is "cdata: array with the shape Vx2xF, where V is the number of vertices (including DG unless specified), 2 is the number of hemispheres (unless specified), and F is the number of rows/features" Link: https://github.com/jordandekraker/hippunfold_toolbox/blob/main/hippunfold_toolbox/plotting.py